# I want to display source class array list into destination class

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to pass Array list from one activity to another activity. I am trying like this: 
I am passing  array list source activity to  destination activity. But the problem is I am getting only the last item at destination activity.

My code is

**source.class**

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
hm.put(KEY_NAME,u);//am adding these values through loop
arl.add(hm);//adding Hash Map to Array List

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SinglePlaceActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", arl

startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
System.out.println("uuuuu"+arl);//upto now working good and display perfectly all array list
```

**destination.class**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = ArrayList<Hash 
Map<String,String>>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println(arl);//am getting what i add last item in the Arrylist at source class 

 Iterator itr = arl.iterator(); 
    while(itr.hasNext())
                      {
    System.out.println(itr.hasNext);//am getting  single last item multiple times.what i add last item in the Arrylist at source class
```

I want to display source class array list into destination class.

Comment: According to the code you presented it seems you are adding only 1 iem to the arl. Where are you adding other items?

Comment: could you post some detail code where you construct your intent and params?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`Bundle.putSerializable()` and `Bundle.getSerializable()`.

Also, in:

```
System.out.println(itr.hasNext);
```

shouldn't it be `its.next()`?

Take also into account that using `Seralizable` object in Android IPC adds a significant overheard with respect to using `Parcelable` objects.